# array printingout backs and prints out only 10 values per line

Tags: arrays

```
public class prac4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
            16, 17, 18, 19, 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33 };

    for(int i=numbers.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        System.out.print(numbers[i]+" ");
        if(i==10)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

For `if(i==10)`, there would be no problem if the given values are less than 30.
However, if there are more than 30 values, and you should print the values backwards, and then at the same time, prints out only 10 values per line, what should you do?

It would be just `if(i%10==0){System.out.println();}`
to print the array, but since it's going to be a reversed array, it's kind of confusing though.

Comment: Please don't use slang in your post, it is unnecessarily  hard on the non-native speakers of English visiting this site.

Answer (score 1):

Either add another variable:

```
int outputCount = 0;
for(int i=numbers.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    System.out.print(numbers[i]+" ");
    outputCount++;
    if(outputCount % 10 == 0)
        System.out.println();
}
```

or calculate it on the fly:

```
for(int i=numbers.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    System.out.print(numbers[i]+" ");
    int outputCount = (numbers.length - 1) - i + 1;
    if(outputCount % 10 == 0)
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Hi Adrian. I've tried both of your codes and the output skips the 9th and 10th array values of 3rd line, and print those out to the 4th line.